# Spring Boot interceptor is not able to retrieve request headers

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a frontend-backend separated project, I'm facing an issue where the Spring Boot interceptor is not able to retrieve request headers. I have configured CORS as follows:

```java
registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("*")
        .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .exposedHeaders("hbb_token")
        .allowCredentials(true)
        .exposedHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE)
        .maxAge(3600L);
```

And in my Nginx configuration:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header Host $Host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header Hbb_token $http_hbb_token;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 30s;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I've tried multiple times, but the interceptor in Spring Boot still receives empty headers. Additionally, there is no preflight request being initiated when the frontend sends requests.

I've encountered this issue several times and haven't been able to find a solution. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

is only null,the request head,and only one requst,no options